# Dynamic table name in Slick 2.0.0.0

Tags: scala, slick, slick-2.0

I would like to pass table name dynamically as given below to TableQuery object, I was able to do in Slick 1.0 as given in this question

[Dynamic table name override in Slick table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20560721/dynamic-table-name-override-in-slick-table)

But not sure 2.0 allow some way to achieve the same.

```
    class MyTable(tag: Tag, tableName: String) extends Table[(String)](tag, tableName){
              def id = column[String]("ROWID", O.PrimaryKey)
              def tNum = column[Int]("T_NUM")
              def tName = column[Int]("T_NAME")
              def * = id
     }

     val tQ = TableQuery[MyTable] filter ...
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Courtesy Richard Pianka : val tQ = TableQuery[MyTable]((tag:Tag) => new MyTable(tag, "SomeTableName")) filter ...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic table name override in Slick table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20560721/dynamic-table-name-override-in-slick-table)